# Variable not adding up other variable values

Tags: c#, winforms, streamreader

I am trying to read from each line in a  file and grab specific strings and integers. However the values of the found integers are not added up at the end and i'm unsure why. I apologize if this is a simple error.

If a `line` in the file contains `"Event Type: Music"`, store `"Music"` in the `EventType[]` array using `MusicTrace`. Music trace begins at 0 and increments each time the string above is found. So it works its way down the array. the array size is the amount of lines in the file to ensure there is always enough array space.

I have another Array for attendance named `EventAttendance[]` which does the same steps above, but cuts the first 18 characters from the found line giving the remaining number (the line in the file is a fixed length). `AttendanceTrace` is used in the same manner a the above `MusicTrace`.

I then have a loop for the EventAttendance array which uses `i` and starts at `0` and carries out code until the `EventAttendance.Length` property is reached. The code adds up the total attendance from each `EventAttendance[]` index using `i`

The code is below:

```
private void frmActivitiesSummary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(sVenueName.ToString() + ".txt"))
    {
        using (StreamReader RetrieveEvents = new StreamReader(sVenueName.ToString() + ".txt"))                    //Create a new file with the name of the username variable
        {
            string[] ReadLines = File.ReadAllLines(sVenueName + ".txt");            //Read File

            int MusicTrace = 0;
            int AttendanceTrace = 0;
            string[] EventType = new string[ReadLines.Length];      //Store found event types
            int[] EventAttendance = new int[ReadLines.Length];      //Store Event Attendance

            string line;                                                            //Declare String to store line

            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(sVenueName + ".txt"))       //Using StreamReader
            {
                while (!file.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = file.ReadToEnd();

                    //Get All Music Event to Array
                    if (line.Contains("Event Type: Music"))
                    {
                        EventType[MusicTrace] = "Music";        //[0] = Music
                        if (MusicTrace != 0)
                            MusicTrace = MusicTrace + 1;
                        else
                            MusicTrace = 1;
                    }

                    //Get All attendances to Array
                    if (line.Contains("People Attending:"))
                    {
                        line.Remove(0, 18);
                        int ConvertedLine = Convert.ToInt32(line);
                        EventAttendance[AttendanceTrace] = ConvertedLine;   //[0] = 10
                        if (AttendanceTrace != 0)
                            AttendanceTrace = AttendanceTrace + 1;
                        else
                            AttendanceTrace = 1;
                    }

                }

            }

            //for each array index and if array index contains music, add this to total amount of music events
            for (int i = 0; i <= EventAttendance.Length; i++)
            {
                if (EventAttendance[i] > 0)
                {
                    if (iMusicAttendance > 0)
                        iMusicAttendance = iMusicAttendance + EventAttendance[i];
                    else
                        iMusicAttendance = EventAttendance[i];
                    }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The Attendance is then show on the click on a button:

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMusicOutput.Text = "After analysis, we can see that Music Events have a total attendance of " + iMusicAttendance;
        lblArtOutput.Text = "After Analysis, we can see that Events have a total Attenance of " + iArtAttendance;
        lblDance.Text = "After Analysis, we can see that Dance Events have a total Attenance of " + iDanceAttendance;
        lblTheatreOutput.Text = "After Analysis, we can see that Theatre Events have a total Attenance of " + iTheatreAttendance;
    }
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. It's *very* unlikely that it's specific to Windows Forms... it's also unclear why you're reading the whole file twice, once reading it with a variable called `line` which is actually the whole file, so may well have multiple lines...

Comment: what values do you get in `iMusicAttendance` ? and what do you expect do get?

Comment: If your issue is attendance counting . you should write line =  line.Remove(0, 18);

Comment: Also, you can replace `if (MusicTrace != 0) MusicTrace = MusicTrace + 1; else MusicTrace = 1;` with `MusicTrace++;`

Comment: That last if statement, why do you need to check if iMusticAttendance is greater than zero before adding `EventAttendance[i]` to it? Do you mean to do if `EventAttendance[i] > 0` ??

Comment: **Mong Zhu**, iMusicAttendance should get a sum value of each Index in EventAttendance[] array.

**Stuart**, I assumed you can't add any integer to an integer of 0

Comment: @Lewis I am talking about numbers, real numbers. I can see what it is supposed to get. Only you can know what value it has in reality. This usually should get you a better picture of what might be wrong. I guess `iMusicAttendance` has the value of the first `People Attending:` line in your file. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and that is supposed to increment. Sorry for my newb errors. I've not know C# for long.

Comment: @Lewis I made an edit to my answer, have a look. It should solve your problem

Comment: I found a solution which works I guess. Assuming you only want the music attendance people. Have a look on my second edit

Answer (score 0):

There where a several useless variables inside your code, that I took the liberty to remove. I also changed arrays for `List<T>` in order to use Linq.

You were adding a `Convert.ToIn32` with the full line, because `String.Remove()` doesn't change the object it's called on but return a new string that you have to assign to something : line = line.Remove(0, 18);

Also, you were doing useless checks for the counters:

```
if (MusicTrace != 0)
    MusicTrace = MusicTrace + 1;
else
    MusicTrace = 1;
```

is the same than

```
MusicTrace++;
```

which leads us to:

```
if (!File.Exists(sVenueName.ToString() + ".txt"))
    return;

List<String> EventType = new List<string>();      //Store found event types
List<int> EventAttendance = new List<int>();      //Store Event Attendance

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(sVenueName + ".txt"))       //Using StreamReader
{
    while (!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = file.ReadLine(); //Declare String to store line

        //Get All Music Event to Array
        if (line.Contains("Event Type: Music"))
        {
            EventType.Add("Music");        //[0] = Music
        }

        //Get All attendances to Array
        if (line.Contains("People Attending:"))
        {
            line = line.Remove(0, 18);
            EventAttendance.Add(Convert.ToInt32(line));   //[0] = 10
        }
    }
}

//for each array index and if array index contains music, add this to total amount of music events        
iMusicAttendance = EventAttendance.Sum();
```

Comment: I changed my code to exactly this and I cant get it to post the Sum Value
I will add the files contents and result after the button for you to view here:
http://imgur.com/bY1vWuf

Comment: @Lewis could you add the text you tested with to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please change :

```
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    line = file.ReadToEnd();
```

to

```
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    line = file.ReadLine();
```

explanation:

You are reading the entire file at once, then you check once your two conditions. But you want to read line by line. So you need to use `ReadLine`.

As for the rest, you declare but never use the `StreamReader RetrieveEvents`. You can get rid of it.

You can use `List<T>` to store the read information. This way you get more flexibility into your code. And the [Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx) can be calculated without a loop.

**EDIT:**

I took the liberty to cut down your programm a little. The Code below should do exactly what you describe in your post:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(sVenueName + ".txt");
List<string> EventType = allLines.Where(x => x.Contains("Event Type: Music"))
                                 .Select(x => x = "Music").ToList();
List<int> EventAttendance = allLines.Where(x => x.Contains("People Attending:"))
                                    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Remove(0,18))).ToList();

int iMusicAttendance = EventAttendance.Sum();
```

**EDIT2:**

seeing your file content it becomes obvious that you want only to sum up the attending people of the music event, but in your approach you sum up all attending people of all event.

Looking at your file it seems you have an offset of 3 lines. So I would suggest, to get all indices of the `Music` lines and then grab only the numbers that are 3 lines further:

```
List<string> allLines = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt").ToList();
List<int> indices = Enumerable.Range(0, allLines.Count)
                              .Where(index => allLines[index].Contains("Event Type: Music"))
                              .Select(x => x+=3).ToList();

List<int> EventAttendance = allLines.Where(x => indices.Contains(allLines.IndexOf(x))).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Remove(0,18))).ToList();

int iMusicAttendance = EventAttendance.Sum();
```

This will get you the sum of only the music people ;) hop it helps.